# Should a Person have multiple honorificPrefixes?

Tags: schema.org

Should a person have several `honorificPrefix`es?

```
<abbr itemprop="honorificPrefix">Prof.</abbr>
<abbr itemprop="honorificPrefix">Dr.</abbr>
<abbr itemprop="honorificPrefix">iur.</abbr>
<span itemprop="givenName">John</span>
<span itemprop="familyName">Doe</span>
```

Or should the title be considered as one long prefix instead?

```
<abbr itemprop="honorificPrefix">Prof. Dr. iur.</abbr>
<span itemprop="givenName">John</span>
<span itemprop="familyName">Doe</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it makes more sense to use only one `honorificPrefix` property, for two reasons:

- Schema.org does not define what multiple `honorificPrefix` properties represent. Should the values be concatenated, or should they be interpreted as alternatives?
- Depending on the used syntax, property values might be unordered. So in case the values would be concatenated, it wouldn’t necessarily be clear if it’s "Prof. Dr. iur.", or "Dr. Prof. iur.", or "iur. Prof. Dr." etc.

A good reason for using multiple `honorificPrefix` properties could be a case where you provide the prefix in multiple languages.